# Losing context in JS function call chain

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have got some JS "objects" I'm using for some complexe stuff. So the following code is reduced to the needed minimal informations:

```
function AttributeWrapper(model) {
    var self = this;
    var attributeModel = model;

    self.labelPrimitive = null;
    self.mandatorySignPrimitive = null;
    self.documentationPrimitive = null;
    self.valuePrimitive = null;

    self.isHidden = function() {
        return false;
    }
}

function Primitive(model, wrapper) {
    var self = this;
    var groupingObject = wrapper;

    self.model = model;
    self.layoutCell = null;

    self.render = function() {

        if (self.isHidden()) {
            return;
        }

        self.layoutCell.getDomElement().innerHTML = self.model.id || "TODO";
    }

    self.isHidden = function() {
        return groupingObject.isHidden();
    }
}
```

This objects are used mainly like this:

```
function AnOtherObject {
    var self = this;

    self.anyFunction = function() {
        var wrapper = new AttributeWrapper(model);
        var primitive = new Primitive(anOtherKindOfModel, wrapper);

        var isHidden = primitive.isHidden();
    }
}
```

For any reason the first call works fine. So the function in the Primitive "class" is called and the scope is correct (variables are set as expected). Also the call by the Primitive class of its contained object (instance of AttributeWrapper) works, but there the context is messed up. I would expect that I can access the instance variables like attributeModel in the "isHidden" function but they do not exist anymore. Also "self" is not the instance but something else (looking like the global "document" or "window" instance), but "this" revers to the instance...
Is there anything i did wrong at the declaration of the objects? I do not understand why the call of the first objects works but the sub-object is wired...

Comment: There are many `self`s in your code. Which `self` exactly becomes `window`? Also, how is it called "first time" and how is it called "second time"?

Comment: "self" of the AttributeWrapper instance during its "isHidden" call by the instance of Primitive

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not very clear.  You have declared a self variable to hold a reference of "this", but in the code above "this" is never out of context.

Remember, inside of function A you have access to the variables in the parent scope. if function B is inside function A it does not.  Therefore, you would create a variable inside of function A to reference the outer scope so function B has access.

You can  pass context into a the function as a parameter, or you can use function.call or function.apply to explicitly set the context of "this".

Comment: Looking at it, your 'primitive' function wouldn't be able to figure out the self being a 'this' since it's not explicitly declared. 

You might be better explicitly stating that the self var is the modal object.

Comment: I would recommend you move away from tracking context with your self variable and move to explicit this binding with the .bind() method.

Comment: I did a quick test of your code and it worked fine. What's the situation that fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved...

I'm using visual studio for debugging. The "return false" of the "isHidden" function in AttributeWrapper was written to place a breakpoint and continue writting the code for this function (to see the objects and their fields in the debugger). When the breakpoint was hitted I had the descript problem.

Today I had a look on it with a colleague who had the idea that maybe just the debugger is confused somehow and do not show the correct state.
So i finished the code and started debugging again. Suddenly the state was correct when the breakpoint gets hit.
So it seems the problem realy was a confused debugger and everthing was working correctly. By using something from the context in the function this confusion seems to be solved...

Lesson learned: visual studio maybe isnt the best choice to debug javascript =)